# Cannot open database "MSCRM_CONFIG" requested by the login - CRm2015

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

CRM2015 - Single server installation on-premise incl. SQL Server 2012 SP

SQL Server Instance named "CRM2015", not on default instance.

For testing purposes I have provided the

> contoso\SVCCRMASYNC

sysadmin rights in SQL Server 2012.
I think with sysadmin there is no higher permissionset I can grant this user,
but nevertheless I get this exception?!

> **CrmTrace encountered an error. Additional Info:Error in**
>   **LoadDeploymentSettings [Cannot open database "MSCRM_CONFIG" requested**
>   **by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user**
>   **'contoso\SVCCRMASYNC'.]**, 
>   Stack Trace :    at
>   System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
>   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.CrmTraceSettings.Load(String traceDirectory)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.get_RefreshTrace()    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.Write(Guid orgId, TraceCategory traceCategory,
>   TraceLevel traceLevel, Int32 skipFrames, String format, Object[] args)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTrace.Initialize()    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.AsyncService.StartServiceComponents(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() (Reporting
>   Process:CrmAsyncService, AppDomain:C:\PROGRA~1\MI818C~1\Server\bin)

[image]

[image]

**Following CRM-Setup.log:**

> Exception caught while checking SVCCRMSANDBOX's access to attribute
>   servicePrincipalName ... Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentNullException:
>   nt4Name ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: nt4Name    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at Microsoft.Crm.ADNameUtility.Rfc1779NameFromNT4Name(String nt4Name)

> Exception caught while checking SVCCRMASYNC's access to attribute
>   servicePrincipalName ... Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentNullException:
>   nt4Name ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: nt4Name    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at Microsoft.Crm.ADNameUtility.Rfc1779NameFromNT4Name(String nt4Name)

> Could not retrieve service information for CISVC:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Service CISVC was not found on
>   computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified
>   service does not exist as an installed service    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateNames()    at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_DisplayName()    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.UI.ServiceDisruptionWarningPage.RetrieveServiceDisplayName(String
>   serviceName)

---

> Line 3393: 11:51:35|Warning| Error while registering Web App Server
>   role in UAL   Line 3394: 11:51:35|Warning| Error while registering
>   Deployment Web Server role in UAL     Line 3395: 11:51:35|Warning| Error
>   while registering Deployment Manager Tool role in UAL     Line 3507:
>   11:51:41|Warning| Error while registering Web App Server role in UAL
>     Line 3508: 11:51:41|Warning| Error while registering Deployment Web
>   Server role in UAL    Line 3509: 11:51:41|Warning| Error while
>   registering Deployment Manager Tool role in UAL   Line 3594:
>   11:51:44|Warning| Error while registering Web App Server role in UAL
>     Line 3595: 11:51:44|Warning| Error while registering Deployment Web
>   Server role in UAL    Line 3596: 11:51:44|Warning| Error while
>   registering Deployment Manager Tool role in UAL   Line 3657:
>   11:51:46|Warning| Error while registering Web App Server role in UAL
>     Line 3658: 11:51:46|Warning| Error while registering Deployment Web
>   Server role in UAL    Line 3659: 11:51:46|Warning| Error while
>   registering Deployment Manager Tool role in UAL

**The following erros I think were logged during the CRM Setup wizard was running.
I forgot to prefix the domain before the user name, but corrected this by clicking back serveral times and entering the correct credentials.
I think this erros can be neglected.**

> 11:47:15|  Error| Check AsyncServiceAccountValidator : Failure: The
>   account specified for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous
>   Processing Service is not valid. The log on name must be specified
>   using either the domain\user or user@domain.com format.
>
> 11:47:15|  Error| Check AspNetServiceAccountValidator : Failure: The
>   account specified for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM application is not
>   valid. The log on name must be specified using either the domain\user
>   or user@domain.com format.
>
> 11:47:15|  Error| Check SandboxServiceAccountValidator : Failure: The
>   account specified for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Sandbox Processing
>   Service is not valid. The log on name must be specified using either
>   the domain\user or user@domain.com format.
>
> 11:47:15|   Info| Check SandboxServiceAccountSecurityValidator:
>   Success 11:47:15|  Error| Check DeploymentServiceAccountValidator :
>   Failure: The account specified for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   Deployment Web Service is not valid. The log on name must be specified
>   using either the domain\user or user@domain.com format.
>
> 11:47:15|  Error| Check VssWriterServiceAccountValidator : Failure:
>   The account specified for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM VSS Writer
>   Service is not valid. The log on name must be specified using either
>   the domain\user or user@domain.com format.
>
> 11:47:15|   Info| Check VssWriterServiceAccountSecurityValidator:
>   Success 11:47:15|  Error| Check MonitoringServiceAccountValidator :
>   Failure: The account or password specified for the Microsoft Dynamics
>   CRM Monitoring Service is not valid. The log on name must be specified
>   using either the domain\user or user@domain.com format.

I have specified the accounts like this:

- contoso\SVCCRMAPPLICATION
- contoso\SVCCRMDEPLOY
- contoso\SVCCRMSANDBOX
- contoso\SVCCRMVSS
- contoso\SVCCRMASYNC
- contoso\SVCCRMMONITORING

Comment: Was the password for the service account 'contoso\SVCCRMASYNC' changed or maybe the service account was changed directly in windows services?

Comment: Possibly that I have changed it under services, cannot remember right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a repair install on your Dynamics CRM installation, and make sure you have the correct username and passwords specified for the service accounts of the Dynamics CRM services. This error sometimes occurs when changing the service accounts passwords, or editing directly the dynamics services account logins in the windows services.

Comment: I did a fresh install of SQL Server and MS Dyn CRM2015 but the problem persists...

Comment: During the repair did set the service users with proper accounts?
as on link below:
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ewvHGW_v5JQ/Vq-qSR86dEI/AAAAAAAAAh0/WjiP_-iZNGM/s1600/serviceaccounts.png

and during the repair did you select the correct CRM2015 instance on the sql server?

Comment: I will try it again. Do I have to set permissions explicitly for the accounts or will they be set automatically by the CRM setup?

Comment: The install setup sets most of the required permissions, so you don't need to set up most of them explicitly. Things like the installation user should be in the Domain Admin users group and full Admin on the server you are installing should be done before installation. This is also pre-setup for the service users in AD as well. 

Please check following link for complete install user and service accounts required permissions. 

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699825.aspx

Comment: From your error i see that the login failed, so that is why i assume you have login details incorrect, but you are not missing permissions. On repair this will fix the login issue, and i assume you should receive a different error for not having permissions, if this is the case.

Comment: Bojane, I have added relevant CRM Setup.log excerpts. You might take a short look at the errors..

Comment: I think I have to configure the SPN's for the service accounts

Comment: If you have Domain Admin permissions for the installation user, the one you are using to install the CRM. I think setup will try to set SPNs for your service accounts, but with those errors install wouldn't pass.

Comment: I can access the CRM Website, Report Manager site, Reports site.
I didn't try to create a Report or anything else...
The installation passes, but I get the errors in the setup log and afterwards I can see the initial errors in the Eventlog as metnioned in the OP.

Comment: I have a domain admin user with local admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If its a local server installation - check in SQL Server Configuration Manager, which protocols you have enabled for MS SQL server instance housing mscrm_config database:

[image]

You could also double check that your firewall isnt blocking the 1433 port for SQL server on the local machine as well.